# Loop over function to build list

Tags: r, plyr

I have a list of functions:

```
func1 <- function(u)
{
    list(val=u, ref="XX1")
}

func2 <- function(u)
{
    list(val=u*u, ref="XX55")
}

func3 <- function(u)
{
    list(val=u-1, ref="XX3")
}
```

And i want to get a result like this with `u=2`:

```
list(XX55=4, XX3=1, XX1=2)
```

For the moment I proceed like that:

```
funcs = c(func1, func2, func3)

temp = llply(funcs, function(f) f(2))
res  = llply(temp, function(u) u$val)
names(res) = llply(temp, function(u) u$ref)
res
```

But maybe is there a more elegant/concise way to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sapply`:

```
sapply(funcs, function(f) {tmp <- f(2); setNames(list(tmp$val), tmp$ref)})
# $XX1
# [1] 1
#
# $XX55
# [1] 341
#
# $XX3
# [1] 11
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to get more used to setNames :)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel. It can work also without using setNames : `sapply(funcs,function(f){x=list(f(2)$val);names(x)=f(2)$ref;return(x)})` gives the same output (that was the answer I was gonna post, only few seconds too late...)